# How to download SNAPSHOT version from maven SNAPSHOT repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, snapshot

So I have a project and I do regular releases to maven without a problem. I now want to make available a SNAPSHOT version of this project. So I do 'mvn clean deploy'. Everything works as you can see below:

[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from sonatype-nexus-snapshots
Uploading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/me/soliveirajr/menta-regex/0.9.6-SNAPSHOT/menta-regex-0.9.6-20111010.153035-2.jar
5K uploaded  (menta-regex-0.9.6-20111010.153035-2.jar)

I go to my sonatype manager and I can find the snapshot:
[image][image]

But now when I try to use this snapshot as a dependency on some other project *in another machine* I get:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>me.soliveirajr</groupId>
  <artifactId>menta-regex</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Missing:

1) me.soliveirajr:menta-regex:jar:0.9.6-SNAPSHOT

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=me.soliveirajr -DartifactId=menta-regex -Dversion=0.9.6-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=me.soliveirajr -DartifactId=menta-regex -Dversion=0.9.6-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

**So how do I force maven to download the SNAPSHOT version to my local (.m2) repository?**

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just add this to your ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>snapshots-repo</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
         <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Nice example, to any readers: please note if you're looking for JaCoCo latest snapshot, don't make the same mistake as I did and copy this example. Because it's a plugin and they have different repo's. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46682942/1546042

Comment: Many newer projects have been shunted onto s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots, so you might need that as well.

Answer (score 37):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that it is also possible by modifying the `pom.xml` of a project, simply add

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>oss.sonatype.org-snapshot</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

to your list of repositories.

In my opinion, this is a better solution than modifying `~/.m2/settings.xml`. The `pom.xml` file will also be available for other project participants through Git and allow them to download the snapshots as well.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16286460/2422744)

Comment: This was super helpful. Small note for those not having a `<repositories>` section, you will need a tag at the beginning of this chunk of code, and it goes at the same level as properties and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, added the missing start tag!

Comment: This is example of how to use SNAPSHOT artifact of regular dependencies and plugins https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/wiki/How-to-use-Checkstyle-snapshot-artifacts

Comment: Can use `settings.xml` in the repo? Then, Git users would get that.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable snapshots in repository config (~/.m2/settings.xml):

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <snapshots>                  <<<<<<<<<<<
                <enabled>true</enabled>    << ADD THIS
              </snapshots>                 <<<<<<<<<<<
  . . .
</settings>
```

See [maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) for more properties.