# maven not able to download jacoco 0.7.10-SNAPSHOT jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I am puzzled by this. I have this in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        ... other plugins ...
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And this my repository section

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-sonatype</id>
        <name>oss-sonatype</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    ..... other repositories ....        
</repositories>
```

As far as i can find out the jacoco-0.7.10-SNAPSHOT is present at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.10-SNAPSHOT/

My understanding is that it should be downloaded and build should succeed but i get the following error

***[ERROR] Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.10-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.10-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]***

I saw solution where people suggested to add the repository in ~/.m2/settings.xml file. 
I want to know can i do this without changing the .m2/settings.xml and why is the current setup not working. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

P.S. Please pardon me if this is already answered somewhere. I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Without knowing how your settings.xml looks like it is not possible to say what the real cause is?

Comment: i don't have any settings.xml

Comment: First suggestion is to use a repository manager and furthermore defined the used repositories in the settings.xml and not in the pom file...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maven distincs between *normal* repositories and *plugin* repositories. You have to define the **plugin repositories** with

```
<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
      ...
   </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: but i have added the repo in the repositories  section which has snapshots. Wouldn't maven look in the added repo to see if the artifact is present?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed that - I fix my answer.