# Sikuli seems to be throwing java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, sikuli

I have created a simple sikuli script within inteliJ however when attempting to execute the script it seems to throw the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

Currently I'm using Java: 11 and I'am using the following Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My Script:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
        Screen s = new Screen();
        //Click on settingimage
        Pattern setting = new Pattern("image1.png");
        s.wait(setting, 2000);
        s.click();
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that SikuliX 1.1.0 is four years old? They seem to recommend version 1.1.4 nightly builds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jens currently I'm unable to find the depedency for: 1.1.4 via mvnrepository

Comment: You can fetch it from the snapshot repository as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715321/how-to-download-snapshot-version-from-maven-snapshot-repository

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Jens Dibbern would I still need to add SikuliX as a maven dependency?

Comment: Yes, but version 1.1.4 SNAPSHOT. You need to check your Maven dependencies to avoid version mix.

Comment: Thanks @Jens Dibbern got it to work by creating a profile within the settings.xml, thanks for your help