# Invoking @PreDestroy on Omnifaces @ViewScoped bean when page is unloaded on iOS

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I am developing a web application using JSF 2.3.9 (Mojarra) and OmniFaces 3.4 in a Tomcat 9 container. On a page I am displaying informations from a `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` bean. This bean is allocating resources in `@PostConstruct` and should release them as soon as the user is navigating to an other page by invoking the `@PreDestroy` method.

This works fine on browsers like Safari on OsX, Firefox, Chrome. But when the web application is launched from Safari on iOS, the `@PreDestroy` method is not called e.g. when the page is left. 
It seems to me that this happens because [the unload() event handler ist not supported in Safari on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) and as I can see the script `unload.js` from Omnifaces binds to this event.

Forgot to mention - it is the latest iOS version 13.2.3...

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Comment: IMO one should not strictly depend on destructors being invoked. Why do you need this cleanup? What if  the user has multiple tabs open or just kills their browser?

Comment: Technically speaking, this is a bug in OmniFaces.

Comment: @Selaron I absolutely agree with you concerning depending on destructors when releasing resources. But I need this cleanup because the ViewScoped Server-Bean streams data from a network device to a JavaScript client implementation. When the user has left the page, the bean should close the resources. Since the bean is ViewScoped, multiple tabs are no problem.

Comment: I created issue in OmniFaces https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/531

Comment: Can you try 3.4.1-SNAPSHOT to see if it's fixed for you?

Comment: Where can I find 3.4.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: You can find it here https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/3.4.1-SNAPSHOT/ If you're using Maven, check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/7715321 how to enable including snapshots in your pom.xml, then you can just use `<version>3.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a bug in OmniFaces. It did never really consider whether `beforeunload` or `unload` event is actually supported. It also did never check the `pagehide` event.

It's reported in [issue 531](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/531) and fixed for OmniFaces 3.4.1 (and 2.7.3).

Basically, the check was improved from

```
var unloadEvent = window.onbeforeunload ? "unload" : "beforeunload";
```

to

```
var unloadEvent = ("onpagehide" in window) ? "pagehide"
    : ("onbeforeunload" in window && !window.onbeforeunload) ? "beforeunload" : "unload";
```

It will first check if `pagehide` is actually supported by testing `"onpagehide" in window`, and when absent, do the same for `beforeunload` where it also checks if there is no (legacy) custom handler, else fall back to `unload`.