# Download dependency from remote maven repository

Tags: maven, azure-devops, maven-2

I have the following pom.xml file which requires downloading various dependencies from azure feed.

[pom.xml](https://github.com/GOrtiz16/openapi/blob/main/pom.xml)

When I want to execute `mvn install`, I get the next error:

> Execution rest-server-generation of goal org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.4.0:generate failed: Plugin org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact pe.com.pichincha:mic-libs-openapi-generator:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in sonatype-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots

The Dependency pe.com.pichincha:mic-libs-openapi-generator:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT exists in azure feed. I think the error is because it is not looking for the dependency in the azure feed repository it looks for it in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots

I don't know why this happens, with other applications I just need to put these lines in the pom.xml file to look for dependencies in the azure feed repository.

```
  <repositories> 
      <repository> 
          <id>t002</id> 
          <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/gz1606/u-devops/_packaging/t002/maven/v1</url> 
      </repository> 
  </repositories>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download SNAPSHOT version from maven SNAPSHOT repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715321/how-to-download-snapshot-version-from-maven-snapshot-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable repository for `SNAPSHOT` versions.

When you want to use additional repository for plugin you need a `pluginRepositories`

[Pom reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#repositories)

So your config can look like:

For project dependencies:

```xml
<repositories> 
  <repository> 
    <id>t002</id> 
    <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/gz1606/u-devops/_packaging/t002/maven/v1</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    <snapshots>
  </repository> 
</repositories>
```

and for plugins:

```xml
<pluginRepositories> 
  <pluginRepository> 
    <id>t002</id> 
    <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/gz1606/u-devops/_packaging/t002/maven/v1</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    <snapshots>
  </pluginRepository> 
</pluginRepositories>
```